# Can we actually do quantum teleportation in IBM quantum computers?

Tags: teleportation, superconducting-quantum-computing

I am going through a course in Quantum computation by NPTEL-IBM, which is designed to introduce Qiskit. In one lecture they describe the concept of quantum teleportation, and point out that since IBMQ doesn't allow two measurements on two different qubits, one needs to modify the quantum circuit.

While doing so, they force interaction between Bob's qubit with Alice's qubit, which in a way is cheating. So can someone explain to me what is happening?

Comment: it would be easier to provide an answer if you included all the relevant background information and context. This includes: a link to the course you are referring to, if available online, and possibly a short summary of what you mean with "they force interaction", and how exactly they are saying to "modify the quantum circuit"

Comment: Without more detail as requested above it's hard to be sure, but I wonder if what's actually happening is that they are interacting Alice's 2 qubits (the qubit to be teleported and Alice's half of the EPR pair), before measuring them individually, rather than (as the standard description of teleportation would have it), doing a joint measurement on those 2 qubits in an entangled basis.

If so there's no "cheating" - the qubits that are being interacted both belong to Alice.

Answer (score 1):

We are actually performing teleportation while using three qubits on the same QPU chip (e.g. Q0 input-qubit, Q1 as intermediate-qubit and Q2 as output-qubit). In this setup the actual teleportation takes place over a distance of few millimeters (distance between qubit Q1 and Q2 on given QPU chip)